# Strange (for me) behavior of YII framework

Tags: php, yii

I use YII framework and I needed to echo out query that is generated with the method `insert($attributes=null)` in `CActiveModel` class which, as it's told in documentation, is in  framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php.

Well, my task was not hard, so I opened this file and edited this method, but nothing happened. After a little head-ache I've found out that my application was importing this class from the folder where I downloaded YII first.

What could be the reason of this behavior? I've solved my problem by changing path but I wonder, is it good solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on `index.php` where you tell your application where to find the classes of the framework, so that's the line you should edit.

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
```

Comment: Thank you. So, I've found correct solution. Oh, and here's my question how can I change this path to `/framework/yii.php` when it's generated.

Comment: When you run `yiic`to create the basic app skeleton, this path is relative to the folder where the framework is located, so I would say that if you remove the yii folder it won't be in the path route.